# asp.net - difference between today and other dates

Tags: asp.net, t-sql

I have a gridview and one of the columns in the gridview is called "last checked" and this is simply a datetime field in a database.

In the "last checked" column instead of displaying a date and time, what I was looking to do was display "7 days" or "1 hour" or "7 mins" etc etc..

In my grdView_RowDataBound sub (or in SQL if easier)...does anyone know what might be the easiest way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Sql-Server, it can be done from the query itself using `DATEDIFF` and `CASE`.

Assuming you need to ignore hours if it is more than a day and ignore minutes if more than an hour from last_checked datetime, you can try this.

```
--Some data to work with
declare @t table ([last_checked] datetime)
insert into @t ([last_checked]) values ('20130127 09:15:21'),('20130128 09:15:21'),('20130128 11:25:21')

--Query
select case when totMinutes >= 60*24 then 
                 convert(varchar(12), totMinutes/(60*24)) + ' day(s)'
            when totMinutes >= 60 then 
                 convert(varchar(12), totMinutes/(60)) + ' hour(s)'
       else convert(varchar(12), totMinutes) + ' min(s)' end timingCol
from (
     select datediff(minute,[last_checked],getdate()) totMinutes
from @t ) X
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I can work this out in the SQL by using something like CAST(DATEDIFF(mi, GETDATE(), GETDATE()+1) AS VARCHAR)

to give me the difference in minutes and then takw it from there with the grdView_RowDataBound sub

Thanks.